# Issue with overwriting a checkbox field through apex

Tags: apex, approval-process, code

```
 if(e.No__c==3 && e.Contact__r.Completed__c==true){            
            e.Contact__r.Completed__c=false;
            System.debug('varcheck02'+e.Contact__r.Completed__c);
            System.debug('ID'+e.Id);
            System.debug('contactCheck'+e.Contact__r.Id);
        }
```

I am working on a apex code: Adding a portion of the code.
Here e is my first object and a lookup is given to contact.

e.No gets update through a approval process(counter value) each time it is approved.
So if it becomes 3 and a checkbox of the related contact is true then it should be overwritten to false according to my condition.

But for some reasons it is not happening.In the debug logs I am receiving the value false for the varcheck02.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're doing this in a trigger. Note that parent/child relationships are not loaded in a trigger, so you'll have to query the contact records first:

```
Map<Id, Contact> contactsById = new Map<Id, Contact>();
for(MyObject__c e: Trigger.new) {
  contactsById.put(e.Contact__c, null);
}
contactsById.putAll([SELECT Completed__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = :contactsById.keySet()]);
Map<Id, Contact> updatedContacts = new Map<Id, Contact>();
for(MyObject__c e: Trigger.new) {
  Contact relatedContact = contactsById.get(e.Contact__c);
  if(e.No__c == 3 && relatedContact?.Completed__c == true) {
    updatedContacts.put(
      relatedContact.Id, 
      new Contact(Id=relatedContact.Id, Completed__c=false)
    );
  }
}
updated updatedContacts.values();
```

Some additional work may be necessary if you expect errors, but this should get you pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

The Contact record is not updated with DML update. You need to execute

```
update new Contact(Id = e.Contact__r.Id, Completed__c = false);
```

This one will work 100%.
I would also try to just run

```
update e.Contact__r;
```

but I don't know if this one will work. Try and write if this one works too.

Even if it is in before insert/update trigger you can't modify related's record fields. You can, but they won't be saved because transaction is performed on another record.

Comment: Yes, the latter works, as a relationship field (e.g. Contact__r) is a full sObject that you can perform DML on.